# How can I split data which printed using ngfor to 3 columns in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, split, html-lists, ngfor

**Data**

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];
```

I want to split that data to 3 columns and want to appers as follow:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    ...
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    ...
    <li>20</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>23</li>
    ...
    <li>30</li>
</ul>
```

How can I split data when using ngfor?

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of arr">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: split `arr` into 3 chunks of arrays

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, it should be like this :

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of arr">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

And add this in your CSS :

```
ul{
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution

Comment: When you have e.g. divs and you don't want them to break just use css style:
    break-inside: avoid;

Answer (score 3):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/slice) :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of arr.slice(0,10)">{{item}}</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of arr.slice(10,20)">{{item}}</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let item of arr.slice(20,30)>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: indexes may dynamic

Comment: @azad if so, op should clarify what he wants

Answer (score 2):

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var results = [];

    while (myArray.length) {
        results.push(myArray.splice(0, chunk_size));
    }    
    return results;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];

// Split in group of 3 items
arr = chunkArray(arr, 3);
```

add nested *ngFor in the HTML

```
<ul *ngFor="let chunckedArr of arr">
    <li *ngFor="let item of chunckedArr">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = 'Angular';
objectKeys = Object.keys;
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];
arr2 = { 0 : 10, 10 : 20, 20 : 30};


<ul *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(arr2)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of arr" >
        <li *ngIf="item > key && item <= arr2[key]" >{{item}}</li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```